# Run query dynamically in store procedure oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

**Problem**

Select all the tables of database where column match than pass table name to next query using loop. If column name and column values matches than return true and exist for loop

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST 
(
 NAME IN VARCHAR2 ,
 ID IN NUMBER,
 RE OUT SYS_REFCURSOR 
) AS

BEGIN
OPEN  RE FOR SELECT A.TABLE_NAME FROM
user_tables A JOIN user_tab_columns C
ON C.TABLE_NAME = A.TABLE_NAME
WHERE C.COLUMN_NAME = NAME;

FOR RE IN LOOP

v_Sql := 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '|| LOOP.TABLE_NAME || 'WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 
ID';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_Sql
IF v_Sql%ROWCOUNT > 0 THEN
return true;
EXIT

END LOOP;

END TEST;
```

For more understanding the problem

```
//Get all the tables of database where campus_id is exist in any table of 
 database
 Campus, Class, Section (3 tables found)
 Apply forloop on the records
 Select count(campus_id) as total from (table name using loop) where 
 campus_id = 1(value 
  pass)
 if(total > 0){

  Exist for loop and return true
 }
  else{
  Again iterate the loop on next value
 }
```

Comment: Ok.  So, is there a question here?

Comment: problem is how i pass the table name to query using for loop

Comment: I edit my question for understanding the problem.

Comment: `Procedures` cant return anything.  Not `true`, not`false`, not `1`, not `42`, not `Hello World`....what is your Business Requirements??